# Sitecore Media Framework Ooyala 1.4 rev. 140411 is not pulling audio files from Ooyala backlot

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

We have upgraded Sitecore 7.2 and Sitecore Media Framework Ooyala 1.4 rev. 140411 in our sitecore instance. We are able to pull videos from Ooayala backlot. However, we could not pull audio files from Ooyala backlot. How to pull audio files from Ooayala backlot?

Please help me on this.

Thank you, 
Annadurai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Media Framework Ooyala doesn't support audio. You need to add your own audio template and add audio asset type functionality(import, export, etc). Follow this document: http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/sitecore%20media%20framework/14/sitecore_media_framework_1_4_integration_guide-a4.pdf.

Also don't forget that audio ooyala player is deprecated, therefore it is not supported by the Player V3. http://community.ooyala.com/t5/Developers-Knowledge-Base/Audio-Player-Will-Not-Play-in-V3/ta-p/3084

Workaround:
Use the Player V2, but for audio only.